# Can I enter Cyprus using Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, cyprus, saudi-citizens

I have a valid Schengen visa from France, and I visited France couple of months ago. I would like to ask if I can access Cyprus without obtaining a Cyprus visa.

Is my Schengen visa enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can enter Cyprus with your valid Schengen visa as long as you have used the visa before to enter a Schengen country.

From [the page](http://www.cyprusembassy.fi/main/index.php?p=Consular_Section/8) of the embassy of Cyprus in Finland (Couldn't find the page of the Embassy in Saudi), also the embassy in Russian [states the same](http://www.mfa.gov.cy/mfa/consulate/consulate_spb.nsf/cgsp10_en/cgsp10_en?OpenDocument):

> Third country nationals, holders of a valid Schengen visa (type: double or multiple entry), who have already entered the Schengen area in accordance with the terms upon which their Schengen visa was issued, may travel to Cyprus without a Cypriot national visa and stay in Cyprus for a period equal to the remainder of the time for which the Schengen visa is valid.