# Can I travel to Cyprus using Schengen Visa?

Tags: schengen, cyprus, cameroonian-citizens

Hi I've got a Schengen multiple entry visa issued from Switzerland to visit my sister in July however I'd like to go to Cyprus first with my friends. Will I need an additional visa if I will be staying in Switzerland for 15 days and Cyprus for 7 days? I am a holder of a Cameroonian passport.

Comment: I think your question is similar to the one in this 

https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71210/can-i-enter-cyprus-using-schengen-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Indian Passport holder, you can travel to Cyprus on Schengen Visa. You won't need an additional visa if your travel dates fall within the validity of the Schengen Visa issued from Switzerland.